# how to overload empty std::initializer_list?

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading, initializer-list

Here I have series of overloaded functions that have as input either vector or initializer_list. And I want to handle the special case when client code inputs empty initializer_list. The problem is that compiler cannot determine what data was supposed in such empty list. So my question is how I address in function declaration such case.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
void func(vector<string> v) { }
void func(vector<wstring> v) { }
void func(initializer_list<string> iv) {}
void func(initializer_list<wstring> iv) {}

int main() {
  using namespace std;
  func({"apple", "banana"});
  func({L"蘋果", L"香蕉"});
  func({}); // special case
}
```

error message:

```
<stdin>: In function 'int main()':
<stdin>:14:10: error: call of overloaded 'func(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)' is ambiguous
<stdin>:14:10: note: candidates are:
<stdin>:5:6: note: void func(std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >)
<stdin>:6:6: note: void func(std::vector<std::basic_string<wchar_t> >)
<stdin>:7:6: note: void func(std::initializer_list<std::basic_string<char> >)
<stdin>:8:6: note: void func(std::initializer_list<std::basic_string<wchar_t> >)
```

`void func(initializer_list<void> iv) {}` - has no effect. I don't know how to properly declare it.

Comment: From what I've tested so far when there is a clash `vector` vs. `initializer_list`, list will win. What overload would you expect to be chosen in scenario where only `vector<string>` and `vector<wstring>` were available, because this seems to be a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to distinguish this with the parameter alone. You can make one of them a template though, which will then be more costly and less preferable for overload resolution

```
void func(vector<string> v) { }
void func(vector<wstring> v) { }
template<typename = void>
void func(initializer_list<string> iv) {}
void func(initializer_list<wstring> iv) {}
```

Now calling `func({})` will prefer the last function over the function template. Note that `func({"hello", "world"})` still prefers the function template over the non-template vector-taking function, because the parameter conversion cost is more important than whether or not a candidate was synthesized from a template.

Answer (score 3):

I'm hoping there's a better answer, but you can exploit the fact that list-initialization with empty braces of a defined type prefers a default constructor to an `initializer_list` constructor.  Unfortunately, this means having to turn the overload of `func` into an overload set of constructors of a single parameter type:

```
using namespace std;
struct parameter {
   // representation left as an exercise - perhaps Boost.Variant?
   parameter(vector<string> v) {}
   parameter(vector<wstring> v) {}
   parameter(initializer_list<string> iv) {}
   parameter(initializer_list<wstring> iv) {}
   parameter() {}  // default constructor - func({}) calls this
};
void func(parameter) {}
```

If you weren't using `string`, you could use a template i.e. `template<typename T> void func(initializer_list<T>)` with an `empty` overload, as non-template overloads are preferred to template overloads, but unfortunately in your case the string literal calls are inferred as `initializer_list<const char *>`, which is difficult to convert to `initializer_list<string>`.

Comment: I like this idea. Perhaps in the constructor you can just forward to one of the original overloads. each of them would just do `funcReal(v);` or `funcReal(iv)`, with the default constructor doing constructor delegation to one of the constructors.